# How to use WEAVE and TANGLE

Tags: tex-core, miktex

I have a MikTeX 2.9 installation on Windows 7. I can use `CWEAVE` AND `CTANGLE` with no issues. If I try

```
WEAVE sample.web null.ch sample.tex
```

I get an error `WEAVE: Read operation failed`.

The version is `WEAVE, Version 4.4 (MiKTeX 2.9)`.

I searched on `MiKTeX` forums in vain. Anyone knows how to fix it, or where I can get an original source of `WEAVE to recompile if necessary?

Comment: With windows you never know if it is a problem with access rights. Does the problem persist if you run the command from a “shell” with admin rights?

Comment: I have MiKTeX installed in one of my computers and I had the very same problem with `weave`. My wild guess is that `weave` is failing due to a problem in path searching. Trying `weave` from TeX Live worked like a charm.

Comment: @uli Thanks, I have been trying with running shell as administrator but still get the same problem.

Comment: @PauloCereda I am just a bit worried to have the two installations installed on the same machine, as there are warnings in TeXLive not to do it. Can you help me do that?

Comment: @mathspasha: I forgot to mention that my TeX Live install is in another computer. `:)` You are absolutely right, it's not recommended to have both TeX distros in the same operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With mathcing [`tex.web`](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/tex.web?revision=7091&view=co) and [`etex.ch`](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/etexdir/etex.ch?revision=24155&view=co) versions (in this case downloaded from the TeX Live SVN), I have no issues:

```
This is WEAVE, Version 4.4 (MiKTeX 2.9)
*1*17*25*38*54*72*99*110*115*133*162*173*199*203*207*211*220*256*268*289*297*300
*321*332*366*402*464*487*511*539*583*592*644*680*699*719*768*813*862*891*900*919
*942*967*980*1029*1055*1136*1208*1299*1330*1338*1340*1379*1598*1599
Writing the output file...*1*17*25*38*54*72*99*110*115*133*162*173*199*203*207*2
11*220*256*268*289*297*300*321*332*366*402*464*487*511*539*583*592*644*680*699*7
19*768*813*862*891*900*919*942*967*980*1029*1055*1136*1208*1299*1330*1338*1340*1
379*1598*1599
Writing the index...Done.
(No errors were found.)
```

However, I *do* see an issue if I have an empty `.ch` file, which your name `null.ch` suggests may be the case:

```
This is WEAVE, Version 4.4 (MiKTeX 2.9)
weave: Read operation failed.
```

So I think this is down to a defective `.ch` file.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why `weave` insists on being given a change file, but an empty change file seems to be the cause of the error.

If you put a comment line in the change file, for example

```
% Comment
```

then `weave` then appears to work.